# What is this enemy called in Dark Souls? Looks like a huge dark hell spawn knight

Tags: dark-souls

[image]

Those are the size comparisons more or less for the demon. And what it's face looked like.

I found him walking around some sort of barracks/watch tower thing on route the "church up high" the NPC told me about, right after the crow picks you up from the Undead Asylum.

He was facing away from me, and I backstabbed him, but I barely scratched him. He turned around and promptly one shotted me for my insolence.

What the hell is this thing? Am I in the right place, progression wise for an enemy to one shot me so easily? I didn't even scratch it!

Comment: Do you mean Dark Souls?

Comment: Assuming it is, I don't understand what you are talking about. You cannot reach the church "right after" the undead Asylum, nor does the church contain any creature fitting your description.

Comment: @Wipqozn: Yes, Dark Souls. My bad. :)

Comment: Black Knight! Epic!

Answer (score 9):

I'm really not so sure what you're talking about either...are you referring to the Dark Knights?

[image]

If so, these guys are pretty powerful at the point of the game you're at - they're placed in locations that you can easily avoid, so for the moment you can run past them and come back to fight once you're stronger.

They also don't respawn so you don't need to worry about having to fight them again after you take them down once.

Comment: This is definitely it. These guys hit like trucks and you have to have a very good understanding of the game and fighting mechanics to be able to kill one early on. "IF" you can kill one though, you are in for a nice treat as they are typically guarding a really nice item like a ring, shield, lots o' souls, stuff like that. :)

Answer (score 2):

The creature that fits your description is a Black Knight and the place you refer to is the watchtower that stands by bridge where the Red Drake lies, in between Undead Burg and Undead Parish. I suppose you are around level 15 and yes, this area is meant for your level, but Black Knights are slightly powerful than normal foes, that's why engaging them is optional.

Go to Undead Parish first and come back later when you have leveled up a bit. You will have no trouble defeating the Black Knight then.

Black Knights are considered mini-bosses and they do not respawn after they are dead (Except for an area where they do respawn, late in the game).

Comment: to me, it sounds like he is running into the black knight guarding the blue tearstone ring inside of the undead burg and not the one past the dragon on the bridge.

Comment: that's what i was thinking, the one down the stairs and at the end of the tunnel guarding the chest